# Calculate hourly fuel consumption using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table of datetime and values. The value is a volume of a tank at the datetime. I want to calculate how much the tank filled / emptied in every hour during the last 10 days.

I measure the tank every 15 minutes, but maybe I will measure it every 20 minutes in the future. I am trying to calculate it using LINQ.

What I did is:

```
allDataView.RowFilter = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
    "DateOfData < #{0}# AND DateOfData > #{1}#", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays((-1) * daysInterval));

allDataView.Sort = "DateOfData DESC";

// making the diff between every sample during the last daysInterval days and put it into a list with these differences.
var result = allDataView.Table.AsEnumerable().Zip(allDataView.Table.AsEnumerable().Skip(1), (row1, row2) => Convert.ToDouble(row1["Value"])-Convert.ToDouble(row2["Value"]));
```

But these are differences between every measurement. What I want is to calculate the differences between samples in round times during that days period.

For example:

```
9:50   0.5
10:05  1
10:20  2
10:35  2.5
10:50  3
11:05  5
```

Than I want to take the latest value that was in 11:00 (3) and take the last value that was in 10:00 (0.5) and to insert it 3-0.5 = 2.5 to a list and continue during that time period.

I want to do it using Linq. Appreciate any help how to implement it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I made it:

```
var groups = from row in allDataView.Table.AsEnumerable()
                         group row by new { Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateOfData"]).Hour, Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateOfData"]).Date } into g
                         select new
                         {
                             FirstDate = g.First()["DateOfData"],
                             FirstValue = g.First()["Value"],
                             LastDate = g.Last()["DateOfData"],
                             LastValue = g.Last()["Value"]
                         };


            var result = groups.Select(grp => Convert.ToDouble(grp.FirstValue) - Convert.ToDouble(grp.LastValue));
```

Answer (score -1):

I'ld recommend creating an sp to handle the grouping of the date time values. This should have the added bonus of allowing your query to run quicker, you shoukld then be able to pull the results out faster via linq.

Comment: Business Logic should not be implemented in DataBase. Additionally BL should be in source safe. [Seperation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Comment: Cheers, however I suggested a simple select of groups in sql server followed by extra functionality done in Linq, which SQL Server will run faster than LINQ can.